# Invalid Token Error while handling button click in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game of tic tac toe and want to get the players to alternate between "o" and "x".  What am I doing wrong , I am getting unexpected token in the HTML whenever i click a button.

here is my JS

```
function click(cell){
    if(player1===0){
        document.getElementById(cell).value="x";
     player1 -=1;
 } else {document.getElementById(cell).value ="o";
player1 +=1;
}}
```

and some of the HTML

```
<tr>
        <td><input  type="button"class= "input" id="cell1" onclick="click("cell1")"></input></td>
        <td><input  type="button"class= "input" id="cell2" onclick="click("cell2")"></input></td>
        <td><input  type="button"class= "input" id="cell3" onclick="click("cell3")"></input></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Put your sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/ for easier to examine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove double quotes around function call on onclick attribute.

```
onclick="click('cell1')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="input" id="cell1" onclick="click('cell1')"></input></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="input" id="cell2" onclick="click('cell2')"></input></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="input" id="cell3" onclick="click('cell3')"></input></td>
</tr>
```

and set an initial value for player1.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="click("cell1")`

> Here `cell1` becomes a **String**. You don't want to do that right.

we need to send the object, use

`onclick="click(cell1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting player1 to 0 explicitly in else loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is a handful of 'wrong' going on there, lets see if this helps any.

In your HTML section, you are incorrectly escaping the quotes for the argument of your 'click' function, so rather than copying the text of the id into the argument, I'd just use 'this.id' in cases where all you need to do is pass in the id of the item being acted on.  No escaping needed when you do that.
The  closing tags are also superfluous, in the context of a button type input, so you can drop those.  No harm in leaving them if you want though.
You also don't have a space before your 'class' attributes in the input elements.

In the JS, I'd not use 'click' as your function name.  Some browsers just plain won't respect it.  Use a different name like 'clickThis' or something else.

Putting all the changes together, you'll end up with this for your js:

```
function clickThis(cell) {
    if (player1 === 0) {
        document.getElementById(cell).value = "x";
        player1 -= 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(cell).value = "o";
        player1 += 1;
    }
}
```

And This for your HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><input  type="button" class="input" id="cell1" onclick="clickThis(this.id)"></td>
    <td><input  type="button" class="input" id="cell2" onclick="clickThis(this.id)"></td>
    <td><input  type="button" class="input" id="cell3" onclick="clickThis(this.id)"></td>
</tr>
```